# how can we pass dataset to web service dynamically is this is best way? what are the other ways to do it

Tags: wcf, ado.net, dataset

how can we pass dataset to web service dynamically is this is best way? what are the other ways to do it?

Comment: Try not to pass types that are specific to .NET, since they won't be usable by other platforms. Try not to pass `DataSet` at all - it is very inefficient.

Comment: then what is the best way to pass the data.

Comment: There's no single "best" way. A much _better_ way would be to create one type per table that would be in the DataSet, then return lists of that type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As John said, don't use Datasets on service boundaries - I wrote a blog article about it [here](http://www.dotnetconsult.co.uk/weblog2/PermaLink,guid,0a7cd196-c36b-4afa-ab02-5e4e6829c42d.aspx)